# UISwitch and UILocalNotification issue

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, uidatepicker, uiswitch

I'm new to Xcode and I am doing an app with UILocalNotifications from UIDatePicker. I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)save {

// Get the current date
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

// Schedule the notification
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Reminder";
localNotification.soundName = @"Alert1.wav";
localNotification.alertAction = @"view";
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

// Request to reload table view data
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

// Dismiss the view controller
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

As you see, the notification will repeat everyday:

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

I want to implement a UISwitch that when is off it will not send any notifications. Like i said, I am new to Xcode and I am a little confused on how to do it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `cancelAllLocalNotifications` method.

```
- (void)switchValueChanged:(SevenSwitch *)sswitch
{
    if (!sswitch.isOn) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
}
```